# DecimalFormat and doubles

Tags: java, formatting, double

[DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) parses [Double.toString()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) representation (which could be in scientific and financial format).

Why Sun has chosen this approach, instead of direct converting double to String?

PS:
To be more concrete. Why DecimalFormat internally uses Double.toString() in order to format Double, instead of formatting internal representation of Double itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct converting"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I don't know what you mean "direct converting double to String". In OpenJDK, Double.toString() returns String.valueOf(value), where value is the primitive double. That in turn gives Double.toString(d), which calls new FloatingDecimal(d).toJavaFormatString(), which finally does the actual work.

Answer (score 2):

DecimalFormat gives you more control over the format by allowing you to give it a formatting pattern.

Comment: Agree with you, but here I am asking about the way DecimalFormat doing formatting internally.

Answer (score 0):

may be he ask like "Double.toString(withSomeParameters)" will do the job instead of using DecimalFormat.

i think the reason, could be i18n. in some places you can type 1,800.39 .. while somewhere else you can type 1.800,39

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure what you mean by "direct converting", but `toString()` is always a debug information only! You should not use it to display values in a frontend. Use `DecimalFormat` for parsing and formatting!

Comment: That I was asking about. Why DecimalFormat internally uses Double.toString() result in order to format Double, instead of formatting internal representation of Double itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Sun is following [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principles.

Answer (score -1):

For *financial* applications, use BigDecimal instead, that give you control over rounding modes and precision.

Comment: Actually, question related to any application which formats double.